# How do one identify the required widget class properties in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently learning flutter and i quiet appreciate the learnng curve. But I have a challenge. The tutorials i have what they kept more emphasis on reading more about flutter widget on flutter.io to know more about the widget. I have done that but i still dont understand it.
E.g: The container class properties have a decoration property. I went to check it on flutter site and i saw it there. But in the decoration properties flutter didn't add BoxDecoration. So how do one know that BoxDecoration must be called when on is using the decoration property of the Container class.

decoration: BoxDecoration(
color:Colors.teal,
borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(12,
[image]
**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

The `Container.decoration` field doesn't expect a `BoxDecoration`, it expect a `Decoration`, which can be a `BoxDecoration`. In Flutter at the time of writing, you can have may `Decoration` implementation, each one having its use case:

- [`BoxDecoration`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxDecoration-class.html) (of course)
- [`FlutterLogoDecoration`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/FlutterLogoDecoration-class.html)
- [`ShapeDecoration`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ShapeDecoration-class.html)
- many other `Decoration` that can be found on the Flutter API...

---

The way you know what widget should be used depend only on what you want to have, and your use case.

For example, you have a widget (eg. `RaisedButton`) and you want to apply a `ShapeBorder` to it. The shape you will choose depend only to form you want your button to have.

It may be a `RoundedRectangleBorder` to apply a custom border radius, or a `StadiumBorder` to apply an harmonized elliptic border radius, and so on...

There is definitively no standard way to create or use widgets in Flutter, everything depend on you, and your knowledge :-)

Comment: Indeed i appreciate your swift reply. thanks a bunch. So what your are saying now is of the fact that he could be this way. **decoration: Decoration(**

Comment: `Decoration` cannot be used directly, it's an abstract class. It's just here to say to developers that **at this place, we want a `Decoration`**, and it's to the developer to choose the **`Decoration` implementation** he want. The same rule apply to `ShapeBorder` and many many other Flutter classes

Comment: Ok. I think i kinda get what you're saying. At the point of using the **Container class** flutter pops up **Decoration decoration, which is the obeject of the Decoration class** . In the flutter io documentation, one have to out of for the Decoration class. And thats were BoxDecoration is talked about to be used with decoration: Decoration.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are in Container Class [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html) and you see under Properties `decoration → Decoration?`. Now clicking on Decoration takes to Decoration Class [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Decoration-class.html)
Here you see on top that it belongs to painting library (Flutter > painting > Decoration abstract class). So, you go to painting library [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/painting-library.html) and look for box decoration and you see BoxDecoration as Class.